Is focus change in HTML instant for CSS purposes?
I have a pair of inputs, where the second input is like a "dropdown": it should only appear when the first input is focused, and then it should be focusable and editable until the focus moves away from the inputs completely.
I tried to implement this using CSS :focus selectors.


input.conditional {
  display: none;
}

input.conditional:focus {
  display: block;
}

input.main:focus~input.conditional {
  display: block;
}
<input type="text" class="main" placeholder="main">
<input type="text" class="conditional" placeholder="conditional">



However, when I focus on the first input, and then try to click on (or TAB into) the second input, it immediately disappears. It looks as if it becomes display: none and unfocusable before it can receive focus.
I tried intercepting the focus/blur events, and even though blur properly has the second input as relatedTarget, there is no follow-up focus event for the second input.
Is there supposed to be a "gap" in focus transition, where the first input no longer has :focus, but the second input doesn't have :focus yet?

When you change focus, you first remove focus from the old element, then add it to the new element. This is not atomic, they're two separate operations, and there's a brief window where no element has focus. This allows the blur event to fire on the old element before the focus event fires on the new one.

I see the behavior you describe (and elaborated by @Barmar) on Edge/Chrome Windows11. However on Safari IOS I see the behavior you want, ie the second input remains visible (and focused) so I have a feeling the telative timings might be different for different browsers.

@Barmar this is not always true. In the :focus-within suggestion in the answer below, the focus manages to somehow stay inside of the container between blur and focus.

I am seeing different effects on different browsers.
Edge/Chrome on Windows11 gives the behavior you describe - the conditional input disappears when focus is removed from main.
However, on Safari IOS it gives the behavior you want - conditional remains visible.
To achieve the desired behavior consistently you could put the two inputs in a container and sense focus within that rather than on the two inputs separately.


<style>
  input.conditional {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .container:focus-within .conditional {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="main" placeholder="main">
  <input type="text" class="conditional" placeholder="conditional">
</div>



